# Perform a file-upload action within WinRT

Tags: c#, windows-8, winrt-async

I spent some reading to figure out how to perform a complete file upload process with Windows RT. The "circumstances" regarding StorageFolder, StorageFile, security box model and such stuff is (at least known, but well known) subjects. Perhaps I started at wrong end, but I hope experts out there can help this question a meaning.

I have a 
- Windows 8 App Store project.
- WinRT Business DLL Project. 
- WinRT Unit Test Project.

This will keep me sure that i work with WinRT related objects.

The question is: 
How do I perform a file stream from my test project to logic in Business DLL project? So I can i.e. stream the uploaded file to application temp folder?

As a paranthese. From within the Windows 8 App Store Project I'm honestly also try to success let the FileOpenPicker give me the stream, not just the filename. The question attached below added some useful information. Though i feel it's more verbose then needed?!

[save stream to file in c# and winrt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13336341/save-stream-to-file-in-c-sharp-and-winrt)

Answer (score 0):

From you test project, you can use [FileIO.ReadBufferAsync](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.fileio.readbufferasync.aspx) to get data into an [IBuffer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.streams.ibuffer.aspx).  Once you have that, you can read or write it with a [DataReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.streams.datareader.aspx) or [DataWriter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.streams.datawriter.aspx) as you please.  Check out [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14499570/how-to-get-a-stream-from-a-byte-array-in-a-windows8-store-app/14507316#14507316) on how to manipulate the data with readers and writers.

Comment: Thank's. It also appear that I have to manually copy the file into a directory which WinRT have access to, when it came to the Unit Test Project. As far as I see, I can just simulate a fileupload with copy the file into Installation StorageFolder. All other possibilites either require me to stream (from unsafe path), path is not read-able or the path are removed after application quits.